# How to checkout an old revision using Subclipse subversion

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, jar, subclipse

I need some help checking out a java project from a SVN repository. In order to validate my work, I created a test java project in my local workspace, and am able to create a jar file of it. But I can not do that with the project that I check out from SVN. This is a project, which others have successfully checked out. Before I started I knew very little about SVN, so I read this url: [How to use Subversion with Eclipse](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-subversion/)
I am using subclipse v 1.6.18
I choose checkout after right-clicking the repository from repository perspective. The developer of the code told me to use revision 10. So I click the selection button, and from the list of revisions I double click revision 10. and click on Finish. [image: pic1]!
 I also choose the "check out as a project in the workspace" and call the project javacardreader. [image: pic2]
Unlike the tutorial I saw on youtube about SVN. I do not see any option to synchronize with the repository in the java perspective. I do see the javacardreader project in my java perspective. But when I try to create a jar file from it, the folder does not show up as an option like my other test project. [image: pic3]
I also do not see an option for adding the binaries to SVN ignor in my list.
My question is what am I doing wrong? My understanding is that revisions are changes / improvements that developer(s) make to the code. One question that came up in my discussion with the developer was if I am pulling the committed code. How can I make sure I am doing that? Where should I look? Am I missing something about how SVN works?